# Multi stage Azure DevOps release pipeline based on different git commits

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps release pipeline using multiple stages, where each stage should be based on a different git commit, but actually, I have some problems.
I created the following pipeline.

[image]

and, in each artifact, I selected the git commit.

In the *Pre-deployment* condition for each stage, I added an **Artifact filter** like the following

[image]

but when I create the release, each stage is taking the _source1 as artifact, instead, I would like:

- Stage 1 - _source1
- Stage 2 - _source2
- Stage 3 - _source3

in order to deploy different version of the code into the different environments.

Any idea?

Thank you!